# A Better code for autofilter sheet to another sheet Visual basic Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

'please who knows a better code for autofilter, advise me how to autofilter to a specific column
'not to the end of the sheet

```
Sub copy_filter_data()

Dim count_col, count_row As Integer
Dim orig, output As Worksheet

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set orig = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)))

ActiveSheet.Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria:=Cells(5, 35).Value
orig.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
output.Cells(5, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: The line `orig.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col))` needs `orig.` before each instance of `Cells`.

Comment: This code does not work in my sheet, I do not know where is the bug. Thanks

Comment: BigBen. I did not copy. Please explain

Comment: You need `orig.Range(orig.Cells(5, 1), orig.Cells(count_row, count_col))....`

Comment: BigBen. It gave me "Run Time error, subscript out of range"